# Excel IF Function, True, False, or Blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Currently trying to compare two dates to work out whether a document has been submitted within SLA dates

I have 3 cells,

```
H5 (SLA target date)
T5 (Document submitted date)
U5 (In SLA or Not) Y/N
```

Using really simple formula in

`U5 of =IF(T5-H5 <= 1, "Y", "N")`

But the formula is returning true down the column for cells which contain no content yet.

How do I return either a Y, N, or 0 (or blank) in column U?

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(T5),ISBLANK(H5)),0,IF(T5-H5<=1,"Y","N"))
```

You can change 0 with "" if you want the cell to be blank.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a check for blank cells

`=if(or(isblank(T5), isblank(H5)), "blank", IF(T5-H5 <= 1, "Y", "N"))`

Answer (score 0):

If both could be empty:

```
=IF(COUNT(H5,T5)=2,IF(T5-H5<=1,"Y","N"),0)
```

Or if `H` column would always be populated:

```
=IF(T5<>"",IF(T5-H5<=1,"Y","N"),0)
```